# Multiple divs with the same height, Jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

i have been attempting to make these 3 divs all of equal height but im finding it rather difficult.

So far i have done this

```
function size() {
var height = -1;
var divs = $("div[class^='content_banner_fill']");
$(divs).each(function () {
    var absolute = $(this).height();
    if (absolute > height) height = absolute;
});
$(divs).each(function () {
    $(this).css("height", height + "px");
});
```

Results...
[image]

Now... i belive it is something to do with the css offsets(Margin/Padding) as the css element height does not include those but have still had no luck.

These 2 css classes are both inherited

```
.content_banner_style {
text-align: center;
margin-top: 20px;}

.content_banner_fill {
padding-top: 20px;
background-color: rgba(202, 202, 202, 0.27);
background-color: rgb(122, 255, 0);}

<div class="content_banner_style content_text content_option_section content_group">
    <div class="content_banner_fill content_col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="res/graphics/icon-clock.png"/>
        <h4>Ease</h4>

        <p style="margin: 15px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent velit neque, ornare et
            orciat,
            vestibulum dictum nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
            rutrum vestibulum augue sit amet lacinia. Mauris pulvinar, est sed porttitor sagittis,
            libero
            odio dictum orci, quis cursus risus nunc sed est. Fusce laoreet rutrum felis, ut auctor
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_banner_fill content_col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="res/graphics/icon-meter.png"/>
        <h4>Ease</h4>

        <p style="margin: 15px;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent velit neque, ornare et
            orciat,
            vestibulum dictum nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum
            rutrum vestibulum augue sit amet lacinia. Mauris pulvinar, est sed porttitor sagittis,
            libero
            odio dictum orci, quis cursus risus nunc sed est. Fusce laoreet rutrum felis, ut auctor
            nulla
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content_banner_fill content_col span_1_of_3">
        <img src="res/graphics/icon-setup.png"/>
        <h4>Ease</h4>

        <p style="margin: 15px;">
            Fanny pack seitan tote bag Truffaut. VHS aesthetic pug, tousled twee plaid raw denim XOXO
            Echo
            Park. Gastropub put a bird on it banjo, Shoreditch synth salvia small batch paleo meh.
            Mustache
            banjo Intelligentsia next level cornhole, small batch fap fingerstache Cosby sweater Austin
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: did you do it inside `document.ready`?

Comment: Would you mind providing both js and your html+css code?

Comment: Yes i did it inside document.ready and window.resize, yes i can post the html and css code.

Answer (score 0):

this isn't written correctly syntax wise.

change this

```
$(divs).each(function () {
    var absolute = $(this).height();
    if (absolute > height) height = absolute;
});
```

to

```
$(divs).each(function () {
    var absolute = $(this).height();
    if (absolute > height) { var height = absolute; }
});
```

edit, this should solve your issue , because it seems that the padding-top 20px is decreasing the bottom of your divs. So just add 20 in the below function and should get you to where you need to be. Adjust accordingly if still not "just right".

```
$(divs).each(function () {
    $(this).css("height", height + 20 + "px");
});
```

Comment: I have tryed that code horse, the issue with that is when the screen resizes it basically... well lets say, the height is 300 and then you risize the screen and that will set the heigt to 320 but if you resize the screen again it sets it to 340... so effectivly if you drag-resize the screen bad things happen XD

Comment: @codehorse Instead of `+20`, better use `.innerHeight()` or `.outerHeight()`. See http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/

Comment: I feel as if i need to re-add/reset the offsets